# Firestore database keeps crashing

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I have successfully migrated my app from RealtimeDB to Firestore but after migrating the app crashes too often with the following error, how to fix this?. I have never run in to this error while using RealtimeDB

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Internal error in Firestore (0.6.6-dev).

   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzejs.run(Unknown Source)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6184)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:788)`

Caused by java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to gain exclusive lock to the Firestore client's offline persistence. 
This generally means you are using Firestore from multiple processes in your app. 
Keep in mind that multi-process Android apps execute the code in your Application class in all processes, 
so you may need to avoid initializing Firestore in your Application class. 
If you are intentionally using Firestore from multiple processes, 
you can only enable offline persistence (i.e. call setPersistenceEnabled(true)) in one of them.

  `at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzefi.start(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeca.zza(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzecc.run(Unknown Source)
   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:428)
   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
   at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:272)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzejp$zza.run(Unknown Source)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)`
```

Comment: Have you opened connection to Firestore many times?
Please specify which SDK and version you are using.
I guess this is an Android Java SDK, right?

Comment: I was having the exact same error. I had wrapped the firestore insertion code with Single of RxJava2 and while subscribing to that I was specifying `subscribeOn(Schedulers.io)`. That was the problem because Schedulers.io was initiating different thread

Answer (score 1):

If you try to access the db from multiple threads, this issue will occur. So if you are using RX, you need to create a single background thread for all insertions. This is because Firestore locks the DB while writing.

```
val FIRESTORE_OPERATION_THREAD = Schedulers.single()
yourSingle.subscribeOn(FIRESTORE_OPERATION_THREAD)
. ...
```

Comment: Database is accessed from multiple threads, and I am not using RX. So this solution will not work for me

Comment: No issues, then Use Executors.
val myExecutor = 
Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()

myExecutor.execute(yourRunnable)
Before using this, read it's documentation once.

Answer (score 0):

What `@Sandip Soni` would work whenever various calls don't interleave each other(like repeated inserts) and by the async nature of Firebase they're likely to do it. What did work for me was a little hack, synchronizing the access to the `Firestore` instance and firing one write operation outside any foreign thread in order to let `Firestore` get the local db instance in it own thread. the write operation is an arbitrary one, it was just for setup purpose:

```
class Firestore {
    companion object {
       val instance: FirebaseFirestore by lazy {
           return@lazy synchronized(Firestore::class){
               FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().apply { lock() }
           }
       }

       private fun FirebaseFirestore.lock() {
          collection("config").document("db").update("locked", true)
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must be using Firestore from multiple processes in your app. Multi-process Android apps execute the code in your Application class in all processes.

To solve the error you may need to:

1. Avoid initializing Firestore in your Application class or in a module for Rxjava. Instead, **initialize a new Firestore instance before every call to the firestore database** like this:

   ```
   val fireStore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
   val settings = FirebaseFirestoreSettings.Builder()
           //offline persistence is enabled automatically in Android
           .setTimestampsInSnapshotsEnabled(true)
           .build()
   fireStore.firestoreSettings = settings
   //go ahead and call database using the Firestore instance
   ```

   This means that you will not use the same Firestore instance for multiple calls.
2. **Then clear your application cache**.

Comment: Please don't add [the same answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52754670/4826457) to multiple questions. Answer the best one and flag the rest as duplicates. See [Is it acceptable to add a duplicate answer to several questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/104227/347985)

Answer (score -3):

Just clear the `Application's cache` in the settings. It's work for me!